# Redirect between subdomains in VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm using Apache 2.2

My site works for these URLs:

- example.com
- en.example.com

So, I would like to redirect everything else (www.example.com, www2.example.com, etc) to example.com

How would I do it respecting those 2 valid URLs?

Comment: When you say "types", do you mean that not only "en", but any ISO 639-1, should work?  This will take a fair bit of configuration.  Alternately, do you simply want any two-letter prefix to work?

Comment: Only example.com and en.example.com should work. All other subdomains should redirect to example.com  I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias en.example.com

    (blah blah blah)
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redirect.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    RedirectPermanent / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

In this order, a client accessing the site without a `Host:` header (e.g. because they're using a very old browser, or because they're reaching the site by typing in its IP address) will load your main site.  If you'd prefer that that type of access be redirected, swap the order of the two entries and remove the `ServerAlias *.example.com` line.

Comment: Beat me to it.  Nice.

Comment: Worth noting: you'll also hit the default VHost if you have a name that doesn't match the template `*.example.com` (e.g. `www.greatestexamplesiteever.com`).  You can of course fix this by either swapping the order of the VHosts or by adding additional `ServerAlias`es to the second VH.